# Drop white shadow in Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, creative-cloud, shadows

How do I create a white drop shadow in Photoshop? The shadow disappears when I change the colour to `#ffffff`.

Steps I have tried to produce a drop shadow:

- Assuming you have two layers (as shown in the image below). Right click on the top layer (in the layers window).
- Select Blending Options.
- In the Layer Style popup, select Drop Shadow (on the left).
- In the Drop Shadow settings change the colour to `#FFFFFF`.
- Click Ok twice.
- You will notice that the shadow has disappeared.

Hope this helps. Please feel free to ask if I didn't explain it right or if there is any ambiguity.

Thanks in advance for the help.

[image]

Comment: By the way, thanks for whoever gave me a votedown for asking a question. Cheers!

Comment: Fair enough @Matt_2.0 Thanks for adding a comment which helps me see what is wrong. I thought my question was clear enough as drop shadow is a commonly used feature. But apparently I was wrong in thinking that. I am going to edit the question now as suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the Drop Shadow Layer Style is set to `Multiply` blend mode.

In order to use a lighter color, first click the small color box to set the color, Then change the **Blend Mode** drop down menu to something *other* than `Multiply`. For lighter colors `Screen` will be more appropriate. However, Luminosity, Normal, Color Dodge will all also result in the lighter "shadow" being visible.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I figured it out. In the layer style window, I selected the drop shadow checkbox and then selected normal from the layer mode dropdown.